# How to troubleshoot a switched-mode power supply?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, troubleshooting

I am trying to repair a switched-mode power supply, but as of now I have no success.

The problem can be described as following:

The supply does not output any voltage whatsoever. The fuse never blows, even though the supply is obviously faulty. There are no indications that any of the components have charred. My multimeter is reading voltage after the rectifier D101, but there is no voltage whatsoever on the secondary side of the transformer T101, so the fault must be somewhere on the primary side of the supply. I am also able to read 315V DC on C111. I tested the components in circuit (with the mains supply off, of course), and they seemed to be fine, so I am really starting to become frustrated.

So do you have any suggestions on how to approach a problem like this one? Are there any specific things that would be sensible to measure?

You can see the schematic below:

[image: power supply schematic part 1]

[image: power supply schematic part 2]

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: If you feel you are qualified to measure on live equipment then report (in your question rather than in the comments) what the voltage is on C111. On a 230 V supply it should be \$ \sqrt 2 230 = 324 V DC \$. You need a properly rated multimeter for this voltage level - not something you bought in the supermarket for €/£/$5. RCD / GFCI gloves and safety glasses are a good idea too.

Comment: I edited my question and added the measurement.

Comment: Considering this oscillator relies on positive feedback to start oscillating, which transfer functions of magnetic phase/gain and sub-circuit transfer function have you not verified yet?

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt I am not sure if I understand what you mean. I am a hobbyist and electronics repair enthusiast, so I am unfortunately not an engineer. I do understand that the oscillator relies on positive feedback, but I don't know what functions you mean.

Comment: In all seriousness, the best recommendation here is to replace the thing. This kind of circuit is not for the inexperienced. There are some quite serious potential safety issues, and as well as that, they are pretty hard to diagnose.

Comment: My observation is this is an ancient design, long before custom controller IC's were common, and may have capacitor issues. Taps 7 & 8 on T101 are part of the feedback loop and voltage regulator, however, as mentioned in comments, this is far more difficult to repair even for an experienced engineer. You have at least 3 feedback loops, one to start oscillation, one to maintain it at high power levels, and another as a voltage regulator. Be smart and be safe. Replace it.

Comment: Most likely Q150,151,101 is blown open circuit. So it you know how a Nfet is switched , you can inject a 9V battery with series R and LED across Drain Source and verify open circuit then connect Gate to 1k to 9V and see is DS conducts

Comment: Thank you for all of your suggestions! I will test those things and then get back to you. @dmb Even though I may not be able to find the fault in this circuit, I am stil very cautious and have quite some experience when it comes to repairing HV electronics, so don't worry. :)

Comment: So I took Q150, Q151 and Q101 out of the circuit and tested them and all of them tested fine! So no, it's not the MOSFETS... I was thinking about the PWM circuit. If the LM358 doesn't output a square wave, the MOSFETS won't switch anyway. But the LM358 needs a +5VDC supply from the secondary side of the transformer T101, which is not there. I will try to inject +5VDC and see whether the PWM circuit will come to life. Maybe something blown on the +5VDC line is pulling the entire line down, making it impossible for the LM358 to work.